# Using Remote Repos in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops

I've successfully connected to a Bitbucket repository within my Jenkins job. My issue is that I haven't been able to find any information about how to access/use the files that the repository contains. I added an "Execute Shell" step after connecting the repo, but don't know where the files the repo contains are. I tried cd'ing into /NameOfRepo/NameOfSubfolder but it says the file/directory does not exist in the console output when I run the job. Where does Jenkins store files it has gained access to that live in a remote repository? Do I need to use shell commands to clone my repo to a specific location?

Comment: The repo is in your current working directory.

Comment: (prolonged sigh) so it is... well... i feel like an idiot. i had even run 'ls' as one of the shell commands to check for that but SOMEhow missed that it had printed out the exact thing i was looking for in the console output. appreciate the response though @tkausl